# I want to generate serial Number automatically by adding plus 1 number in asp.net web api

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-apicontroller

How to take dataset and get max serial number from database generate number automatically by adding plus 1 number

```
 var SerialNo = Convert.ToInt64(row[0]) + 1;
```

is this example is correct

My API

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/boq/getserialno/{id}")]
public BOQ GetBoqSerialNo(long id)
{
        var result = new BOQ();

        var dsBoq = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(AppDatabaseConnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, 0, "GetSerialNo", new SqlParameter("@FinancialYearId", id));

        if (dsBoq.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        { 
            DataRow row = dsBoq.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            var SerialNo = Convert.ToInt64(row[0]) + 1;         
            result = new BOQ
            {
                SerialNumber = Convert.ToInt64(row[0])
            };
        }
        return result;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSerialNo]
    @FinancialYearId BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(SerialNumber) AS SerialNumber 
    FROM BillOfQuotation
    WHERE FinancialYearId = @FinancialYearId
END
```

Comment: why not use a `Sequence Numbers` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: From the look of the code in their API, @Squirrel , it seems they want to update the existing value(s) in the table, not have the next inserted row have the next number in the sequence. Unless I'm reading wrong? But then the query underneath certainly tries to do what you describe. The latter is just going to suffer problems from race conditions though; an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` is the right choice there. Not actually sure what behaviour the OP is after. :/

Comment: @Larnu. Yes your are right. It is a bit confusing with the question

Comment: Actually i want the next inserted row have the next number in the sequence. Whenever the new record is added the serial number should automatically generate new number in sequence

Comment: Then you want an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` @KeepWatchingMadaniChannel .

Answer (score -1):

You may update your query by this:

```
  string SQLString = "
  UPDATE s  SET s.SerialNumber= t.rno from BillOfQuotation  as s 
  inner join (
   select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1000)) as rno, * from 
  BillOfQuotation where FinancialYearId=@FinancialYearId ) as t 
  on s.col1=t.col1 and s.FinancialYearId=t.FinancialYearId 
  where s.FinancialYearId=@FinancialYearId "     ----- here apply join as per the unique values in your table
```

Here we are generating unique row_number for each row and update it respectively as Serial No. If you have some column or id maintained for ordering then you may use that column instead of `select 1000`.

Comment: While that might work, your suggestion would be vastly improved by explaining your proposal. A little formatting to make it readable would also be an improvement. And perhaps you can highlight the fact that this updates every row in the table - and using no particular (and therefore consistent) order.

Comment: @SMor: We don;t know about the table structure and more over I am just giving an example or you can say direction for their code, since they have their database so they better know how to use this in our code. And still comment section is open for all if they need any help, always welcome.... :)